# What's the difference between touchcancel and touchend events?

Tags: html, dom, touch-event

After reading this [event_touchcancel](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_touchcancel.asp) doc:

> The touchcancel event occurs when the touch event gets interrupted.

> Different devices will interrupt a touch event at different actions, and it is considered good practice to include this event to clean up code if this "error" should occur.

and [w3c event-touchcancel](https://w3c.github.io/touch-events/#event-touchcancel). I am still confused.

What does "when the touch event gets interrupted" means? Is there any specific situation that interrupts the touch event? When will touchcancel event be triggered?

Comment: I see that this important question has been unanswered for 6 months. Hope someone clarifies the situation.

Comment: w3schools is trash. The official spec you've linked to says the event indicates "a touch point has been disrupted in an implementation-specific manner," and even provides examples "such as... the touch point leaving the document window into a non-document area..." That seems pretty clear

Answer (score 3):

> The touchcancel event occurs when the touch event gets interrupted.

Semantically, it is used to detect when a touchpoint is no longer active.

A touchpoint can be disrupted in a number of different ways, for example:

- If the user's finger is removed from the touch screen on a multitouch active state.
- If the user switches to a different app (abruptly) or if the device loses power.
- If the user's finger moves outside the browser window or the element that they are interacting with, effectively to prevent the user from accidentally interacting with elements outside the intended target.

In all these cases, the touchpoint gets “disrupted” and the `touchcancel` event should be fired to handle the forthcoming expected behavior.

**Behavior in Browsers:**

There is a w3c specification on web APIs for touch events, but is completely implementation dependent.

Example implementation being, [`touchCancel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/touchcancel_event) is a child object/class of [`touchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent), which is a child object/class of [`UIEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) and that is handled by `WindowsEventDispatcher`. Example [handling](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/gfx/layers/apz/util/APZEventState.cpp#314) of canceling touch by a gfx callback helper.

Apple, similarly, has [`touchCancel`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/event/1618206-touchcancel/) type property that defines as "A system event canceling the current touches for the control.", and is a child/inherits from [UIControl](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/event) Event structure. But it also has broader type implementation, e.g., For an event where a finger is dragged inside the bounds of the control ([touchDragInside](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/event/1618240-touchdraginside)). All such types listed [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/event).

Chromium also used `touchEvents`, e.g., `touchCancel`, for touch scrolling and gesture handling, but no longer [[1]](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/a-more-compatible-smoother-touch/) [[2]](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/blink-dev/c/wHnyukcYBcA) do so in favor of a gesture recognizer [[3]](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/aura/gesture-recognizer/) in the [[code]](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:ui/events/gestures/gesture_recognizer.h;drc=3344b61f7c7f06cf96069751c3bd64d8ec3e3428;l=67).

I found explicit developer documentation that specify when to trigger `touchCancel` related events in [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/event). They have predefined types and specs on when to use them. MDN has documentation of their type UI event, but not explicit spec on exactly when to use them. I couldn't find Chromium doc/spec of `touchEvents`, you are [welcome](https://source.chromium.org/search?q=touchCancel&ss=chromium&start=1) to explore the code.

Edit: correctly specified an example + added section.

Comment: The first case (the user's finger is removed from the touch screen) would trigger a touchend event, not touchcancel. This answer might be more useful with documented references to what conditions trigger this event in actual browsers.

Comment: Yes, `touchEnd` is more precise than `touchCancel` in that case. Edited that and added some browsers info. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a device that can at most cope with *four* concurrent touches.  What happens if the user adds a thumb, meaning a fifth touch has started?  It's up to the device whether to ignore the new fifth touch, or to discard one of the previous touches in favour of recording the new one.  If a previous ongoing touch is to be jettisoned in favour of the new one, a `touchcancel` event might be fired by the device.  This is distinctly different from a `touchend` event because it's not caused by the user.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).